# $k$ balls into $n$ bins: how to formally account for "time"

Tags: probability-theory, problem-solving

We throw balls into the bins until no bin is empty. What is the expected time until no bin is empty?

The solution goes: 
Let $Y$ be the random variable that counts the time until no bin remains empty. We write $Y$ = Sum of $Y_i$.

$Y_i$ is the time since we had $(i-1)$ nonempty bins, until we have $i$ nonempty bins.

Usually I would think about this as $k$ independent balls into $n$ bins and the sample space is clear here.

The $Y$ random variable is very intuitive, but how does one formalize it? What is the sample space? And how can we justify the passage from the $k$ balls into $n$ bins sample space into the one I'm asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am a bit confused as to how the $k$ ball limit is imposed here. In the solution below, I assumed that there were an unlimited supply of balls.

After the $(j{-}1)^{st}$ bin gets a ball, the expected time before the $j^{th}$ bin has a ball is $\frac{n}{n-j+1}$, thus the expected time to fill all $n$ bins would be
$$
n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{n-j+1}=n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}
$$

---

The argument above uses the [Linearity of Expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity). The part that seems a bit magical upon first sight is that $\mathrm{E}[X+Y\;]=\mathrm{E}[X]+\mathrm{E}[Y\;]$ even when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Below is an argument that computes all the probabilities and yields the same answer.

The [Generalized Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/counting.html) says

Let $\{S_i\}$ be a finite collection of sets from a finite universe. Let $N_j$ be the the sum of the sizes of all intersections of $j$ of the
$S_i$; thus, $N_0$ is the size of the universe. Then, the number of elements in exactly $k$ of the $S_i$ is
$$
\sum_{j\ge k}(-1)^{j-k}\binom{j}{k}N_j
$$
Suppose we've thrown $k$ balls. If we let $S_i$ be the arrangements where bin $i$ is empty, then we have
$$
N_j=\binom{n}{j}(n-j)^k
$$
that is, $\binom{n}{j}$ ways to choose the $j$ empty bins and $(n-j)^k$ ways to place the $k$ balls into the remaining $n-j$ bins.

Since there are $n^k$ ways to throw $k$ balls into $n$ bins, the probability of getting exactly $1$ bin empty after throwing $k$ balls is
$$
\frac{1}{n^k}\sum_{j\ge1}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{j}{1}\binom{n}{j}(n-j)^k
$$
The probability of getting the last bin with the next ball is $\frac{1}{n}$ and that would be after $k+1$ balls.  Thus, the expected number of balls would be
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\ge0}\sum_{j\ge1}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{j}{1}\binom{n}{j}(k+1)(1-j/n)^k\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j\ge1}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{j}{1}\binom{n}{j}\left(\frac{n}{j}\right)^2\\
&=\sum_{j\ge1}(-1)^{j-1}\binom{n}{j}\frac{n}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j\ge1}(-1)^{j-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-k-1}{j-1}\binom{k}{0}\frac{n}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j\ge1}(-1)^{j-1}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n-k}{j}\frac{n}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n-k}\\
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The theoretical approach is to consider a sample space that consists of all *infinite* sequences of ball throws. For each such sequence, $Y$ is then the length of the shortest prefix that hits all bins. There are some sequences for this this is not well defined because some bin will *never* be hit, but the probability of having *any* of those sequences is 0 (that's the Infinite Monkey Theorem), so we can just ignore them, or let $Y$ have some dummy value in those cases.

Because the sample space is infinite, the combinatorial principle of counting happy outcomes and dividing by total outcomes won't work here; instead we need to move to the more abstract framework of *probability measures*. However, with some cleverness one can get a lot of mileage out of the assumption that successive throws are *independent*, even without worrying too much about the theoretical basis. See the [coupon-collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) for derivations in this particular case.